# The Cake GetVersion - Duplicate 'AssemblyInformationalVersion' attribute

Tags: c#, cakebuild

For some reason, there is an [error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0579) during cakebuild.net task execution.

The root cause of error is [`UpdateAssemblyInfo = true`](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.GitVersion/GitVersionAliases/4B9950AF) property. It's look like attribute duplication happens.

But it's not obvious why it happens for me. Could you pls, reveal such kind of behavior

**Prerequisites:**

- Net 4.7.2
- Not **AssemblyInformationalVersion** attribute in .csproj
- Not **AssemblyInformationalVersion** attribute in Properties\AssemblyInfo

  ```
  var gitVersion = GitVersion(new GitVersionSettings
               {
                   OutputType = GitVersionOutput.Json,
                   NoFetch = false,
                   UpdateAssemblyInfo = true
               });
  ```

**Error:**

Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(41,12): error CS0579: Duplicate 'AssemblyInformationalVersion' attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [SDK style projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview) `AssemblyInfo` will always be generated (unless `<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>` is set). The generated `AssemblyInfo` will contain some version information, regardless whether you set `<AssemblyInformationalVersion>` explicitly, or not.

So: Setting `UpdateAssemblyInfo=true` in `GitVersion` creates an `AssemblyInfo`, and your `csproj` also creates one. Hence, the error.

What you can do: Get the version and set build properties accordingly, so the generated `AssemblyInfo` contains the information you want it to.

```cs
Task("Build")
.Does(() => {
   // get version
   var gitVersion = GitVersion();
   var version = gitVersion.SemVer; // or something other...
   Information($"Building version: {version}");

   // add version to settings
   var settings = new DotNetBuildSettings();
   settings.MSBuildSettings = new DotNetCoreMSBuildSettings();
   settings.MSBuildSettings.Properties.Add("AssemblyVersion", new[] { version });
   settings.MSBuildSettings.Properties.Add("AssemblyFileVersion", new[] { version });
   settings.MSBuildSettings.Properties.Add("AssemblyInformationalVersion", new [] { version });
   settings.MSBuildSettings.Properties.Add("Version", new [] { version });

   // build
   DotNetBuild("./console/console.csproj", settings);
});
```